# Methods to control environment when starting a lettuce test suite

Tags: python, hudson, lettuce

I'm building a test framework that will have a top level Gherkin interface backed by Python/Lettuce.  We want to build it in to our continuous integration infrastructure (Hudson) as well as have the same tests be easily runnable on any environment (dev-int, qa-int, stage, etc).  Since you can't pass parameters through to the test on the command line, the approach I've been thinking of is:

> Hudson Job
>
> 1. sub-job that dynamically builds a configuration file on machine that will
>      run tests based upon desired test environment
> 2. sub-job kicks off lettuce on runner machine, terrain file then picks up
>      values from the dynamic config to run tests against correct environment
> 3. sub-job deletes config file

While this will work, it seems like a hacky work-around to me.  I've been googling around, but it seems like even the guy who wrote lettuce thinks configuration shouldn't be necessary, and if you want it, you should just set environment variables outside the test then read them from inside terrain.  Short of re-engineering lettuce to be able to pass command line arguments, can anyone think of other ways to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Nothing is forcing you to use the built-in `lettuce` command line interface. You can write your own Runner class or `lettuce_cli.py` replacement without difficulty.

Comment: Do you have to use Hudson or you can use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) instead? In the latter case you use Matrix builds in conjunction with [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). I can elaborate if indeed using Jenkins is an option.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot Nope, we just have Hudson...  looks like for now at least, we are going with the method outlined above.  I wish we had a better solution though...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what lettuce was like back then, but there is the `world` object [(outlined here)](http://lettuce.it/reference/terrain.html#world). The author admits that this is a little un-pythonic, but you can do something like this:

```
from lettuce import Runner, world

runner = Runner('path/to/tests', verbosity=4)
world.VAR_NAME = VALUE
result = runner.run()
```

And in your `terrain.py` file you can access the world value like so:

```
from lettuce import step, world

@step('step definition')
def function my_step(step):
    print world.VAR_NAME
```

These world variables are available for the duration of this test suite, so be mindful of the amount of information you put into your world

Comment: We moved away from lettuce anyway, but this really misses the point.  The whole point is to configure the test environment separately from the test code, so stuffing a bunch of values in the pseudo-global namespace that is `world` doesn't really solve the problem.  Also, pseudo-global namespaces are just bad.  Very bad.